# Bindings in light dom

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I **cannot** use `dom-bind` template (for a set of reasons defined by where I use polymer) so I had to create element `<global-scope>` and put all other elements inside its light `DOM`. But I really lack of binding:
For instance I have:

```
<global-scope> 
    <data-provider data="{{datasource}}"></data-provider>
    <data-consumer data={{datasource}}></data-consumer>
</global-scope>`
```

Neither can I use template `dom-repeat` in light-dom either (because of absence of bindings).
Is there a comprehensive way to compensate bindings, that would be natural for end-user (like as if I was using dom-bind)?

Answer (score 0):

No, `dom-bind` was built exactly for that purpose. If you can't use `dom-bind` and not put your elements into the shadow-DOM or shady DOM then there is no way to use binding.

Comment: there must be a way, I believe, someone played with templatizer, though I don't have enough expertize in Polymer/javascript to understand how to make it work for me

Comment: That's what `dom-bind` does. Why would something similar be of any use if you can't use `dom-bind`?